# Firebase emulator token revoked

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I have been using the Firebase Emulator for quite some time now and everthing have been working fine. Recenttly, I set up some seed data with a user in the seed as well.

My problem is that each time I start the emulator (with the seed) and I try to execute an action, the `auth.verifyIdToken(token, true)` throws an error: `The Firebase ID token has been revoked`.

Do I need to reconnect each time I start the emulator or is it a bug ?

Comment: Are you getting a fresh token after restart or trying to use a token from a previous run?

Comment: I don't get a new token after a restart (maybe because I don't export on exit). My token is revoked but I'm still connected.

Comment: Does creating the users with a particular UID help? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2749